# builder.go:204] Error: build error: timeout while waiting for remote repository

Tags: git, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I have openshift origin with one master and two nodes.App deployment works fine if I deploy app on node where master is installed.But whenever I try to deploy app in second node it gives me error saying:

```
builder.go:204] Error: build error: timeout while waiting for remote repository
```

Could anyone please tell me what could be the issue?

I have already checked DNS setting to docker and docker containers can reach to internet.

Comment: are you able to pull an image from dockerhub on your openshift environment? And what happens when you try to perform your build-command with an increased loglevel (oc new-build ... --loglevel=5)

Comment: Hi , even with increased log levels it gives same message:

Error: build error: timeout while waiting for remote repository "https://github.com/priyanka5/openshiftexample"

Comment: @lorenzvth7 could you please help me with this ? I am struggling to find out the resolution. I am able to create app in first node but seeing this error message while building app in second node.

Comment: yes I can pull images from docker hub and also I am able to do "git clone" in openshift environment , but issue is when I create app on my second node of installation. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @priyank have you found the solution, I installed openshift origin using ansible. I'm also getting the same error. Please post the answer if you found a solution.

Comment: @priyank https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/9080

Comment: @Balakrishnan sorry for late response, no the issue  is not resolved yet.